# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - static Header & Footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have some special Layout with Bootstrap 3. I need some static header and footer. The problem is that it's an responsive layout in which it is bad to use positions someone told me.

Like this:

[image]

Do you have any Ideas?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: I would like to do this - but the Problem is my Code is not helpfull for it. It's Only 4 div's but i don't know if there is any possibillity with Bootstrap - and without using own position's because it will brake the full responsitivity.

Comment: you obviously played around with `.navbar-fixed-top`. build something on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ and show us what you got so far and what exactly you are expecting it to do

Comment: Here i did some test's - http://bit.ly/1fPtxpC - It looks right but the header && Footer is not fixed ...

If i use fixed classes it looks like this: http://bit.ly/1i85e32 - Border at footer not working and content overlapping!

Base Question: Will using position's break responsitivity at all?

Answer (score 4):

Use .navbar-fixed-bottom, and .navbar-fixed-top on your header and footer containers.

Comment: There are a few Problem's with doing this: 1) everything will scroll also the left navigation in the content area wich should be fix as well 2) the scrolling content will be overlap with the header also if i set an z-index > 100 3) Bottom no Border is working

Answer (score 0):

Or give both a unique class. And add:

```
.classname{position:fixed;}
```

Comment: The Question is - will it stay responsive after doing it with positions?

Comment: I don't think this will remain responsive